# Cause of 180 degree phase shift of reflected light

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, visible-light, reflection, boundary-conditions

When light originating from a medium of lower refractive index reflects off a surface of higher refractive index, why does the phase shift by 180 degrees? Stokes relations show that the reflection coefficients at the surface are equal but of opposite signs depending on direction (i.e. from lower to higher refractive index versus higher to lower); but this relation does not say exactly which one is shifted by 180 degrees. Can someone please provide an explanation for this. I have researched the internet with no success.